# Reload React application every minute for five minutes

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, reload

Is there a simple way to reload the React application with `window.location.reload`every minute for five minutes if the user stays on that specific site. If the user goes to the home page of the application it should not refresh the page if time is left.

I tried something like

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const RefreshComponent = () => {
  const [refreshCount, setRefreshCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (refreshCount < 5) {
        window.location.reload();
        setRefreshCount(refreshCount + 1);
      }
    }, 60000); // 60000 milliseconds = 1 minute

    // Stop refreshing after 5 minutes
    setTimeout(() => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }, 300000); // 300000 milliseconds = 5 minutes

    return () => clearInterval(interval); // Clean up interval on component unmount
  }, [refreshCount]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Auto Refresh Component</h1>
      <p>Refreshing in {5 - refreshCount} minutes</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RefreshComponent;
```

But this actually will refresh the page forever.

Comment: It'll refresh your page forever because you're handling the count in the `useState` and will be reset to `0`  after refreshing the page. try to save the count in the `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` and fill the state from there. Now, you will be able to get count of the page refreshes.

Comment: Yes that could work. But what to do if user leaves the page that should be reloaded?

Comment: LocalStorage won't be removed, if user left the page. You need to read from localstorage first while mounting the component, and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you need is the expiration time rather than the timer:

```
const RefreshComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const expires = Number(localStorage.getItem('Expires') ?? Date.now() + 5 * 60 * 1000);
    localStorage.setItem('Expires', expires.toString());

    let tid: number | undefined;
    let timeLeft = expires - Date.now();
    const countdown = (t: number) => {
      if (timeLeft > 0) {
        tid = window.setTimeout(() => {
          window.location.reload();
          timeLeft = timeLeft - t;
          countdown(60 * 1000);
        }, t);
      } else {
        localStorage.removeItem('Expires');
      }
    };
    countdown((timeLeft % (60 * 1000)) || 60 * 1000);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(tid);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Auto Refresh Component</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RefreshComponent;
```